# How to set different weight of line according to the data?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts, baidu

## The problem

I'm creating a tree diagram using Echarts.

I want to change the weight of the line according to the value of data.

Expected image:

[image: expected image]

Image is for illustration purposes.

It would be helpful if you could give me advice.

## The code

This is my Javascript configuration using [ECharts editor page](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html) :

```
option = {
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
            triggerOn: 'mousemove'
        },

        toolbox: {
            show: true,
            feature: {
                dataView: {
                    show: true,
                    title: 'Data View',
                    readOnly: false,
                    lang: ['Data View', 'Close', 'Update']
                },
            restore: { show: true, title: 'Update' },
            saveAsImage: { show: true, title: 'Save Image as PNG' }
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                type: 'tree',

                data: [{
                     "name": "1",
                     "children": [
                      {
                       "name": "2-1",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "Easing", "value": 70},
                        {"name": "FunctionSequence", "value": 30},
                        {
                         "name": "interpolate",
                         "children": [
                          {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "value": 100},
                          {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "value": 50},
                          {"name": "DateInterpolator", "value": 40},
                          {"name": "Interpolator", "value": 20},
                          {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "value": 10},
                          {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "value": 70},
                          {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "value": 60},
                          {"name": "PointInterpolator", "value": 20},
                          {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "value": 30}
                         ]
                        },
                        {"name": "ISchedulable", "value": 20},
                        {"name": "Parallel", "value": 50},
                        {"name": "Pause", "value": 40},
                        {"name": "Scheduler", "value": 40},
                        {"name": "Sequence", "value": 55},
                        {"name": "Transition", "value": 30},
                        {"name": "Transitioner", "value": 10},
                        {"name": "TransitionEvent", "value": 20},
                        {"name": "Tween", "value": 60}
                       ]
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "2-2",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "DirtySprite", "value": 80},
                        {"name": "LineSprite", "value": 50},
                        {"name": "RectSprite", "value": 20},
                        {"name": "TextSprite", "value": 99}
                       ]
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "2-3",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "FlareVis", "value": 30}
                       ]
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "2-4",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "DragForce", "value": 99},
                        {"name": "GravityForce", "value": 20},
                        {"name": "IForce", "value": 35},
                        {"name": "NBodyForce", "value": 20},
                        {"name": "Particle", "value": 50},
                        {"name": "Simulation", "value": 80},
                        {"name": "Spring", "value": 40},
                        {"name": "SpringForce", "value": 10}
                       ]
                      }
                     ]
                }],

                top: '1%',
                left: '7%',
                bottom: '1%',
                right: '20%',

                symbolSize: 10,

                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        lineStyle: {
                            width: 5
                        }
                    }
                },

                label: {
                    normal: {
                        position: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        align: 'right',
                        fontSize: 9
                    }
                },

                leaves: {
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            position: 'right',
                            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            align: 'left'
                        }
                    }
                },

                expandAndCollapse: true,
                animationDuration: 550,
                animationDurationUpdate: 750
            }
        ]
    };
```

However, all the lines become thick as shown below.

Actual image:
[image: Actual image]

Answer (score 2):

by adding *lineStyle* to a data item [see full Code](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWxgCeIWxA5GDllkwDRUUAmAhmH7Ey1aqjFjo_ALaNYTAIxcekgMYALCABtebaCNWTKx49LnMATAFpl3U-q279hh8aSxz8pgFF-GCGgAcy5YADd-bQBXeQB2AAZYAF97NzEPL2YAMSjoNUgYAGUsAEcYvI5OcMiY4gBmRJSjNwk0yUyFQLBcEGBtQUrmtM0dPSwDUiG2jNlvABEBgElobpxe_rBgHFCI6PkAFkbUtskZiwVl1fXBLZ2a-Ut445PJbUCsQrpteQ81Pq3mGxeEwkk0XqdPLNmABZQR4AAelx6fRu2yqu1qsEURymDgAurjJGDwWdvItCposLwov0AEbfO57YiPZLPaaQ85MAAK_BwkW-2kZmIArDjwcgOd4eVFsEKDmKSZLmBSNFSabg5cRDqzCeklQpimVxmpKtUmbBhcKdeLScwACp86ABArQTWwBrWxUdJgO_hOiAujXo-7EbGel62hS-_0unxhcZgN0s4kR_U-gDu7FdwfNADYnrBda93p9aN9iL9_jhAVTQumILwwBpQ1aUski7ACW0Uw5Wm1vTZLCoXiNnONXF6oQo5hAcHRCiA8N03QAOBWp70AGRLi4Dpox8lF4ZOkaYACUsPkF0v9yHYMm2WlT3asPCwNe926AJxfqod6hvNAHxfD8sB_NoAIKEEbDjEwrLti8eKPqYgHAWWoHgZBTDQVmcE9qY-HuB2A7WHUw4nKOYwTCQp5ZP0bAAGoQBgboekkXZpE0uIcUSRhISgRibCAzCKAApORAFYAAZmAzCxOJj60sAYCbDIIkKUYeBBBoskKI8GlGBgtAyEp2iFBAABe8jYtwRh7jIpbliYZhbDIkQVriqGOT8ur1o2zYWriSRDMFRK2a8_C0lg2geaY0Cue5zmmL0zpQBMTDfDJEnGPGc4QGokQAIJvEE6UyA2vAMshFCRBApWAnVOnZZIUkwO-lnyF-IVGFxrxYPw8ZEElYh0tFsUOPFOBuTFw3JcAqUwA12mJtV1C5ZABXaMVdVlRVVW6rV9UKJliZBd1YUCZIr4gH6vCFdAvAAMJ9P0IDYMQrAxI-foQG5LpzFEfIusQlpPEYP1_WlANA2lACqIACN0xCxKKPChZ2KBJAA3EAA)
[image]

```
data: [ ...
  { name: 'Tween', value: 60, lineStyle: { color: 'red', width: 15 } }
]
```

Comment: That's awesome! Could you please add some code in your post, for instance the `data` part, or the items you added a `lineStyle` to, or at least one of them?